# WYSIWYG with rulers

Tags: reactjs, ckeditor, tinymce, wysiwyg

I use react project to develop letter editor application. but, i need to adding rulers (like ms. word) for users to tidy up the format. you guys have some experience about this? (WYSIWYG)

WYSIWYG with rulers for react project